# How can I create python strings with placeholders with arbitrary number of elements

Tags: python, placeholder

I can do

```
string="%s"*3
print string %(var1,var2,var3)
```

but I can't get the vars into another variable so that I can create a list of vars on the fly with app logic.
for example

```
if condition:
  add a new %s to string variable
  vars.append(newvar)

else:
  remove one %s from string
  vars.pop()
print string with placeholders
```

Any ideas on how to do this with python 2.6 ?

Comment: That seems hopelessly complex.  Why build a big format string and a big list of values?  Why not apply the format to the value and append that to your results?  Please show some more of the context in which you think you need this.  It sounds like it can all be simplified.

Comment: I'm not completely sure what you're trying to accomplish here, but I'll take a stab at an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about this?

```
print ("%s" * len(vars)) % tuple(vars)
```

Really though, that's a rather silly way to do things.  If you just want to squish all the variables together in one big string, this is likely a better idea:

```
print ''.join(str(x) for x in vars)
```

That does require at least Python 2.4 to work.

Answer (score 3):

use a list to append/remove strings then "".join(yourlist) before printing

```
>>> q = []
>>> for x in range(3):
    q.append("%s")
>>> "".join(q)
'%s%s%s'
>>> print "".join(q) % ("a","b","c")
abc
```

Comment: absolutely agree - don't do this! BUT, if for some reason you REALLY want to be able to _remove_ formatting from your string (urgh!) then this seems the simplest way. MUCH better to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
n = 0
if condition:
  increment n
  vars.append(newvar)

else:
  decrement n
  vars.pop()

string = "%s" * n
print string with placeholders
```

But you don't really need string formatting if you're just joining the vars; why not do:

```
"".join( map( str, vars ) )
```